# convert date style php to print in rss

Tags: php, date

I have 'date' table at data base

dates are stored like this:

**2013-04-28 01:43:06**

I want to 'echo' dates like this:

**Sun, 28 Apr 2013 17:56:31 +0000**

because I want to use it at rss page.

how to do that?

thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php > $tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
php > $dt = new DateTime('2013-04-28 01:43:06', $tz);
php > echo $dt->format(DateTime::RSS), "\n";
Sun, 28 Apr 2013 01:43:06 +0000
```

Refer to the "[Date and Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)" section of the PHP Manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
$date = 2013-04-28 01:43:06;
$date_rss = date('D, d M Y H:i:s',strtotime($date));
Echo $date_rss;
```

**This will output**

```
Sun, 28 Apr 2013 17:56:31
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `strftime` function. You can format your dates any way your heart desires.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$datetime = "2013-04-28 01:43:06"; 
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime /*, new DateTimeZone('UTC')*/);
echo $d->format("D, d M Y H:i:s O"); // or any format you want
```

Result:

```
Sun, 28 Apr 2013 01:43:06 +0000
```